# how to connect ESSBase cube with OBIEE 12 c

Tags: obiee, essbase

I'm using OBIEE version 12.2.1.4.0 and ESSBase version 11.1.2, when I'm trying connect the OBIEE with ESSBase cube I'm getting error below
The connection has failed essbase error 0, and sometime I'm getting other error code like 46
Please find attached for your reference
[image]

please find log for your reference

```
2021-07-22T22:24:12.992+05:30] [OBIS] [ERROR:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ssi] [tid: 2d8c] Essbase Error 46 [[
file: C:\ADE\fanzha_h122140_24\biserver\analytics\server\Query\Execution\DbGateway\DbGatewayEssbaseCAPI\PrivateInclude\SQXDGEssbaseCAPIImport.h; line: 66
]]
[2021-07-22T22:25:29.579+05:30] [OBIS] [ERROR:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ssi] [tid: 2d8c] Essbase Error 46 [[
file: C:\ADE\fanzha_h122140_24\biserver\analytics\server\Query\Execution\DbGateway\DbGatewayEssbaseCAPI\PrivateInclude\SQXDGEssbaseCAPIImport.h; line: 66
]]
[2021-07-22T22:25:39.700+05:30] [OBIS] [ERROR:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ssi] [tid: 2d8c] Essbase Error 46 [[
file: C:\ADE\fanzha_h122140_24\biserver\analytics\server\Query\Execution\DbGateway\DbGatewayEssbaseCAPI\PrivateInclude\SQXDGEssbaseCAPIImport.h; line: 66
]]
[2021-07-22T22:26:13.276+05:30] [OBIS] [ERROR:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ssi] [tid: 2d8c] Essbase Error 46 [[
file: C:\ADE\fanzha_h122140_24\biserver\analytics\server\Query\Execution\DbGateway\DbGatewayEssbaseCAPI\PrivateInclude\SQXDGEssbaseCAPIImport.h; line: 66
]]
[2021-07-22T22:26:53.280+05:30] [OBIS] [ERROR:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ssi] [tid: 2d8c] Essbase Error 7274601 [[
file: C:\ADE\fanzha_h122140_24\biserver\analytics\server\Query\Execution\DbGateway\DbGatewayEssbaseCAPI\PrivateInclude\SQXDGEssbaseCAPIImport.h; line: 66
]]
[2021-07-22T22:27:41.163+05:30] [OBIS] [ERROR:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ssi] [tid: 2d8c] Essbase Error 7274601 [[
file: C:\ADE\fanzha_h122140_24\biserver\analytics\server\Query\Execution\DbGateway\DbGatewayEssbaseCAPI\PrivateInclude\SQXDGEssbaseCAPIImport.h; line: 66
]]
]]
[2021-07-23T09:56:30.568+05:30] [OBIS] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ] [tid: e28] LCMAPIsUtil.GetSDD-> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata
[2021-07-23T09:56:30.625+05:30] [OBIS] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ] [tid: e28] Reading ServiceInstanceKey from file: C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata\components\OBIS\instance_mapping\obis1\mapping.xml [[
file: server\Utility\Server\Config\SUSystemConfig.cpp; line: 1371
]]
[2021-07-23T09:56:30.648+05:30] [OBIS] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ] [tid: e28] Found service instance key: ssi for component:obis1 [[
file: server\Utility\Server\Config\SUSystemConfig.cpp; line: 1562
]]
[2021-07-23T09:56:30.674+05:30] [OBIS] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ] [tid: e28] LCMAPIsUtil.GetSDD-> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata
[2021-07-23T09:56:30.702+05:30] [OBIS] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ] [tid: e28] LCMAPIsUtil.GetSDD-> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bin\..\..\user_projects\domains\bi\bidata
[2021-07-23T09:56:30.774+05:30] [OBIS] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ssi] [tid: e28]  [46158] Admintool is using language ENU.
[2021-07-23T09:56:50.620+05:30] [OBIS] [NOTIFICATION:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ssi] [tid: e28] Opening call for File=C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\bi\bifoundation\server\TestEssbase.rpd, ID=11713544998400275304_14988947945299578211, LogicalName: OfflineRepository
[2021-07-23T09:56:57.184+05:30] [OBIS] [ERROR:1] [] [] [ecid: ] [sik: ssi] [tid: e28] Essbase Error 2097266 [[
file: C:\ADE\fanzha_h122140_24\biserver\analytics\server\Query\Execution\DbGateway\DbGatewayEssbaseCAPI\PrivateInclude\SQXDGEssbaseCAPIImport.h; line: 66
]]
```

Comment: What does the nqsadmintool.log say?

Comment: hi chris, please find the log

Comment: Are you running your whole OAS/OBI on that machine or is it jsut an Admin Tool installation?

Comment: @Chris I'm running both Whole OBIEE and ESSBase on same machine

Comment: On what kind of host operating system?

Comment: @Chris it's windows 10

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the update. Referring to the official certification matrix here: It is not supported to run OBIEE 12.2.1.4 on a desktop operating system in the first place:
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/obiee-122140-certmatrix-4472983.xlsx